# How to render something above Ext.Viewport

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have viewport:

```
new Ext.Viewport({
  layout:'fit',
  hideBorders:true,
  items:[panel1,panel2,panel3],
});
```

Now i want to show combobox above viewport:

```
var myCombo= new Ext.ComboBox({
  store:myStore,
  editable:false,
  renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
  triggerActions:'all',
  mode:'local',
  cls:'scales'
});
```

css:

```
.scales{
  position:absolute,
  botton:1em,
  right:1em,
  background-color:white
}
```

But its render in leftside. How to render its in right botton?

**UPDATE**

Now i put combo into Panle:

```
myPanel= new Ext.Panle({
items[myCombo],
renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
cls:'scales',
border:false
});
```

Now my combo in right-bottom. But look like this:
[image]

Even i delete viewport code from app i get same result. can i do something with combo?

Comment: You can't. Viewport will take the entire body. Go for a panel instead of Viewport if you want to make the combobox visible

Comment: @ javapirate: can you give a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CSS is broken, that should be:

```
.scales{
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Notice the semicolons and `bottom` instead of `botton`.

EDIT:

You should render your combo into a window to let Ext manage positioning problematic. Here's an example that renders a minimalist window:

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
    closable: false
    ,resizable: false
    // uncomment to make the window draggable
    //,title: '...'
    ,border: false
    // uncomment to make the window modal
    //,modal: true
    ,items: [{
        xtype: 'combo'
        ,store: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
    }]
});

win.show();

// then use anchorTo to position the window where you want:
win.anchorTo(Ext.getBody(), 'br-br', [10, 10]);
```

See the doc for [`anchorTo`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Window-method-anchorTo).

Comment: In my code all right. I just make mistakes when whrite a question.

Comment: Hm. Ill try to use window.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
      layout:'fit',
      items:[panel1,panel2,panel3],
});
```

Or put your combo inside the viewport items as:

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
  layout:'fit',
  items:[panel1,panel2,panel3, combo],
});
```

Comment: try playing with your layout config. Right now you seem to use `layout: fit` in the main panel. Try with `layout:auto` or `layout:vbox`